# What does 9:41 mean?

Tags: iphone, ipad

As you may have noticed, the time in iPhone/iPad advertisements has always been 9:42 am, and it's recently (?) switched to 9:41.

Why the original 9:42, and also, why the switch?

Comment: Basically, the time shown in the screenshot is set to be the approximate time the product is announced in the keynote address: http://secretlab.com.au/blog/posts/ipad-day-941-am/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard it was used because that was the approximate time at which the iPad was revealed originally, and given the Apple attention to detail, the clock had to match up. It was used in everything else because a lot of the same materials were used in the presentations as in the ads.